# Having apache problems

Tags: apache

I recently downloaded Apache. both the Apache and MySQL are green however when I click the admin button for both of them they load "Not Found HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.". The only thing I changed when I downloaded it was the port number which I changed from 80 to 8081 because 80 was already been used. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: On the page that it tries to load, does it have the new port (which might show as https://localhost:8081/phpmyadmin or something similar)? If not, have you tried adding the host to the URL?

Comment: Are you using some packaged kit like XAMPP or WAMP? I'm not aware of any green status indicator for the stock MySQL or Apache installations.